# problem serial hardware sim7600 arduino due

Tags: serial

I am very newbie using arduino. I get a EVB SIM7600 TTL 3V and I am trying to test it using a arduino Due.
I need a help please, my simple code doesnt work.
The serial monitor only show zeros. The baudrate default for SIM7600 is 115200bps. I insert a simcard and then write AT command in serial monitor, for example ATI... I received zero

Here is my code and photo of connection.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Testing GSM SIM7600");
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

}

void loop() {

  if(Serial1.available())
  {
    Serial.println(Serial1.read());
  }

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    Serial1.write(Serial.read());
  }

}
```

Comment: I didn't see anything like AT Command in your sketch. Share your full sketch.

Comment: I send command AT using Serial monitor text box. I can connect to module using the  built in usb serial interface, then using putty com5 baudrate 115200 I can use them and even access to internet like a modem LTE. The complete sketch is same I posted :S still i can not do anything :( with arduino due

Comment: let go to step by step and solve the problem. You direct interface of module from USB to you PC and then try to send AT commands. Please don't forget to use EOL characters like `\r \n` at the end of AT command like this `AT\r\n`.

Comment: the serial usb interface of SIM7600 is working fine in windows. The problem is arduino due communication, but I know can understand the problem is a code I wrote. I checked yesteday the display work better using Serial1.readString (), but still I have searching the solution. sorry my english